# An integral inequality (one variable)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Anyone has an idea to prove the following inequality?

Let $g:\left(0,1\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable
and $r\in\left(0,1\right)$ such that 
$$
r\left(g"\left(x\right)+\dfrac{g'\left(x\right)}{x}\right)\geq\left(g'\left(x\right)\right)^{2},\forall x\in\left(0,1\right).
$$
Prove that 
$$
\left(\intop_{0}^{1}e^{-g\left(x\right)}xdx\right)\left(\intop_{0}^{1}e^{g\left(x\right)}xdx\right)\leq\dfrac{1}{4\left(1-r\right)},\quad\quad {(\star)}
$$
provided the LHS is finite.

---

Further comment: This inequality comes from a contest for undergraduate students in my university.

If we take the function 
$$
g\left(x\right)=-r\ln\left(-\ln\left(x\right)\right)
$$
 then we have 
$$
r\left(g"\left(x\right)+\dfrac{g'\left(x\right)}{x}\right)=\left(g'\left(x\right)\right)^{2},\forall x\in\left(0,1\right).
$$
By using Mathematica, we can see that for this function
$$
\left(\intop_{0}^{1}e^{-g\left(x\right)}xdx\right)\left(\intop_{0}^{1}e^{g\left(x\right)}xdx\right)=\dfrac{1}{4}\Gamma\left(1-r\right)\Gamma\left(1+r\right).
$$
Moreover, we also can check that 
$$
\dfrac{1}{4}\Gamma\left(1-r\right)\Gamma\left(1+r\right)\leq\dfrac{1}{4\left(1-r\right)},\forall r\in\left(0,1\right).
$$

Comment: " the initial data"? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: yes $g$ must be defined at 0 or 1 or somewhereelse. for instance what is the value of $g(0)=?$

Comment: $g$ has a domain (0,1). We don't care g(0) or g(1).

Comment: I other word cant you solve and ODE without initial data?

Comment: I am missing something from your answer [By Euler Reflexion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) we have $$\Gamma\left(1-r\right)\Gamma\left(1+r\right)=r\Gamma\left(1-r\right)\Gamma\left(r\right)= \frac{rπ}{\sin(rπ)}$$ I am curious to see how you prove that $$\frac{rπ}{\sin(rπ)}≤\frac{1}{1-r}$$ I couldn't prove that

Comment: it is not hard but why don't you show me how you prove . you are just talking about mathematica . is that how you prove things?

Comment: Couldn't you show $\sin\left(\pi x\right)-\pi\left(1-x\right)x\geq0,$
$\forall x\in\left(0,1\right)$ ?

Comment: Does $g(x)$ have to be undefined for $x=0$ and $x=1$?

Comment: I think you may assume $g\in C^{2}([0,1])$ in order to prove $(\star)$. The general case follows by approximating.

Comment: This is a comment for the Mods; how come Binjiu can offer a bounty greater than his/her own rep? Is this a thing now?

Comment: Hi Kevin, My rep. was subtracted automatically via the system once I offered this. Don't worry about that. If it's not enough, do you think that I am still able to make this offer?

Comment: I haven't seen this level of questions in undergraduate maths contests, at least not on the university level (maybe on a city/country level, though I don't have experience there)

Comment: Did you try the Polya Szego inequality?  Not saying that it works, but looking at how the two integrands are almost inverses, it might

Answer (score 7):

This one is quite fun. Allow me to share some reasoning (**not an answer yet!**), which I believe might be helpful.

First, let's rewrite the ODE inequality in equivalent ways:

$$r\left(g''+\frac{g'}{x}\right)\geq g'^2$$

$$g''- \frac{g'^2}{r}+\frac{g'}{x} \geq 0$$

$$g''e^{-g/r}- \frac{g'^2}{r} e^{-g/r}+\frac{g'}{x} e^{-g/r} \geq 0 $$

Introducing a new function:

$$f(x)=e^{-g(x)/r}$$

We obtain an inequality:

> $$x f''+f' \leq 0$$

Or (provided $f' > 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$):

$$( \ln f' )' \leq - \frac{1}{x}$$

Not sure how this might be useful yet, but we'll see.

---

Now we play with (*). Our inequality becomes:

$$\left( \int_0^1 f^r xdx \right) \left( \int_0^1 f^{-r} xdx \right) \leq \frac{1}{4(1-r)}$$

Changing the dummy variable in the second integral we have equivalent expression:

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x)^r f(y)^{-r} xy~dxdy \leq \frac{1}{4(1-r)}$$

Introducing:

$$u(x,y)=\ln f(x) - \ln f(y)$$

We have:

> $$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 e^{u(x,y)r} xy~dxdy \leq \frac{1}{4(1-r)}$$

---

Expand both sides as Taylor series in $r$ (since $ r \in (0,1)$ the geometric series converges):

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(1+ur+\frac{u^2r^2}{2}+\dots+\frac{u^nr^n}{n!}+\dots \right) xy~dxdy \leq \frac{1}{4} \left(1+r+r^2+\dots +r^n+\dots \right)$$

> While not necessary, it is sufficient if each term on the left is $\leq$ than each term on the right for respective powers of $r$. This might be used as proof, in case it turns out to follow from the ODE inequality. *(This part is now obsolete, since this condition is indeed too strong, see Update 2 for further details).*

First terms are equal:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x y dx dy=\frac{1}{4}$$

For the other terms we are supposed to somehow use the ODE inequality to show:

> $$I_n=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\ln f(x)-\ln f(y) \right)^n x y ~dx dy \leq \frac{n!}{4} \tag{1}$$

Funny thing is, $r$ kind of disappeared from the problem statement (provided we can prove the inequality by term in the general case).

---

**Update**

Let's consider (1) when $n$ is odd. It is quite clear that:

$$I_{2k+1}=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\ln f(x)-\ln f(y) \right)^{2k+1} x y ~dx dy =0, \qquad k \in \mathbb{N}$$

Proof. Let's introduce a function $\ln f(x)=h(x)$:

$$I_{2k+1}=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(h(x)-h(y) \right) \left(h(x)-h(y) \right)^{2k} x y ~dx dy =$$

$$=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 h(x) \left(h(x)-h(y) \right)^{2k} x y ~dx dy-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 h(y) \left(h(x)-h(y) \right)^{2k} x y ~dx dy$$

But both integrals are the same, since we can always change the dummy variable. Thus:

$$I_{2k+1}=I-I=0$$

Which means we only need to prove the even case of (1):

> $$I_{2k}=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\ln f(x)-\ln f(y) \right)^{2k} x y ~dx dy \leq \frac{(2k)!}{4} \tag{2}$$

Which can be rewritten as:

$$\sum_{l=0}^{2k} \frac{(-1)^l}{(2k-l)!l!}  \int_0^1 h(x)^{2k-l}  x~dx \int_0^1 h(y)^l y ~ dy \leq \frac{1}{4}$$

---

**Update 2**

> From a comment by Binjiu below, it is apparent that requrements $(1)$ and $(2)$ are too strong, and **they are not true for the example from the OP** (as could be checked directly for $k=1$).

I am still leaving that part of the post intact, as it shows which way we can't go.

---

Now the problem could be reformulated in another way (where we include the odd terms from the right hand side):

> Prove that if for $f:\left(0,1\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the inequality $x f''+f' \leq 0$ holds for all $x \in (0,1)$ then there exists $r \in (0,1)$ such that:
>
> $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\ln f(x)-\ln f(y) \right)^{2k} x y ~dx dy \leq \frac{(2k)!}{4} \left(1+r \right) \tag{3}$$

I believe this can be written without $r$ as just:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\ln f(x)-\ln f(y) \right)^{2k} x y ~dx dy < \frac{(2k)!}{2}$$

Comment: Just a quick observation. Suppose that your idea works then in the end you indeed prove a stronger inequality, instead of $\frac{1}{4\left(1-r\right)}$, with the RHS $\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^{2k}=\frac{1}{4\left(1-r^{2}\right)}$. However, by the example that I gave, you can check that this bound is not the case. That is, the inequality (2) is not true.

Comment: @Binjiu, I have edited. Thank you for noticing this. I still think the reformulation of the problem (3) may be helpful. If you notice any more issues, I'd be happy to fix them

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=g(e^{-x})$, then
$$r\left(g''(x)+\frac{g'(x)}{x}\right)\ge g'^2(x)\iff rf''\ge f'^2$$
and
\begin{align}
I&=\left( \int_0^1 e^{-g(x)} xdx \right) \left( \int_0^1 e^{g(x)} xdx \right)\\
&=\left( \int_0^{\infty} e^{-f(t)} e^{-2t}dt \right) \left( \int_0^{\infty} e^{f(t)} e^{-2t}dt \right)\tag{$x=e^{-t}$}
\end{align}
Let $h(x)=e^{-f(x/2)/r}$, then
$$rf''\ge f'^2\iff h''\le0$$
and
\begin{align}
I&=\frac14\left( \int_0^{\infty} h(s)^r e^{-s}ds \right) \left( \int_0^{\infty} h(s)^{-r} e^{-s}ds \right)\tag{$s=2t$}\\
&=\frac14\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{h(t)}{h(s)}\right)^r e^{-t}e^{-s}dtds
\end{align}
Now the problem becomes

> Let $h:\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R_+$ be a twice-differentiable and concave function, let $r\in(0,1)$, prove that$$J=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{h(t)}{h(s)}\right)^r e^{-t}e^{-s}dtds\le\frac1{1-r}$$

Let $s>0$, since $h$ is concave, we have
$$\forall t>0,\ h(t)\le h'(s)(t-s)+h(s)$$
As $t\to0$, since $h$ is positive, we have
$$h'(s)\le\frac{h(s)}{s}$$
Note that $h$ is positive and concave so is increasing, we have
\begin{align}
\forall t>0,\ \frac{h(t)}{h(s)}&\le\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $t\le s$} \\
t/s  & \text{if $t>s$}
\end{cases}\\
&\le\frac{t}{s}+1
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
J&\le\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} (s+t)^r s^{-r}e^{-t}e^{-s}dtds\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\Gamma(r+1,s) s^{-r}ds\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-r}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$(1):$ Incomplete Gamma function,
$$\int_0^{\infty} (s+t)^r e^{-(s+t)}dt=\int_s^{\infty} u^r e^{-u}du\tag{$u=s+t$}$$
$(2):$ Integration by parts,
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\Gamma(r+1,s) s^{-r}ds&=\left[\frac{\Gamma(r+1,s) s^{1-r}}{1-r}\right]_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}s^re^{-s}\frac{s^{1-r}}{1-r}ds\\
&=0+\frac{\Gamma(2)}{1-r}
\end{align}

---

**Update:**

As mentioned by @Binjiu, we can give a sharper bound by using directly:
$$\forall s,t>0,\ \frac{h(t)}{h(s)}\le
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $t\le s$} \\
t/s  & \text{if $t>s$}
\end{cases}$$
This yields
\begin{align}
J&\le\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{s} e^{-t}e^{-s}dtds+\int_0^{\infty}\int_s^{\infty} t^r s^{-r}e^{-t}e^{-s}dtds\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\int_0^{\infty}\gamma(1-r,t)t^{r}e^{-t}dt\tag{3}\\
&=1+r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1-r}\\
&=1+\frac{r}{2}\left(\psi\left(1-\frac r2\right)-\psi\left(\frac {1-r}2\right)\right)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$(3):$ [Lower incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function),
$$\gamma (1-r,t)=\int_0^ts^{-r}e^{-s}ds=-r\gamma (-r,t)-t^{-r}e^{-t}$$
$$\gamma (-r,t)=t^{-r}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}t^{n}}{n!(n-r)}$$
$(4):$ [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function),
$$\psi\left(\frac {z+1}2\right)-\psi\left(\frac {z}2\right)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+z}$$
Below is the comparison of these two bounds. The maximum difference is $\ln2$ as $r\to1$.
[image]

Comment: That's excellent.

Comment: By improving a bit of your method, $$
\dfrac{h\left(t\right)}{h\left(s\right)}\leq1\text{ if }t\leq s;\dfrac{h\left(t\right)}{h\left(s\right)}\leq\dfrac{t}{s}\text{ if }t\geq s,
$$ we obtain the sharper estimate in the RHS $$
\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{r}{8}\left(H\left(-\dfrac{r}{2}\right)-H\left(-\dfrac{r}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right).
$$ Here $H$ is the "Harmonic Number". (The calculation is due to Mathematica.)

Comment: @Binjiu Thanks for your comments.  I realized that but just thought it could be more "elegant"  to get exactly $\frac1{1-r} $ :D

Comment: Thank you for this amazing solution. I learned quite a bit. +1

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks to your inspiring substitution